Combining Blazor Server with ASP.NET Core API and .NET MAUI
I'm developing a small-scale order management system for my company and considering the following architecture:
Client Interface: A Blazor Server application hosted on an ASP.NET Core server, allowing clients to create orders via the web.
Employee Interface: A .NET MAUI application for Android devices, enabling employees to search and process orders.
Shared Backend: Both interfaces would interact with a common ASP.NET Core API hosted on the same server, facilitating data management and reducing infrastructure costs.
This setup aims to streamline development and deployment by utilizing a single server for both client and employee interactions.
My questions are:

Is this architecture advisable for a small-scale application?

What potential challenges or limitations should I be aware of when hosting both Blazor Server and the API on the same server?

Are there best practices or alternative approaches that might better suit this scenario?


I appreciate any insights or experiences you can share regarding this architectural approach.
I'm aware of the need for proper authentication and authorization mechanisms to ensure secure access for both clients and employees.
